# Take first word after a regex match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract some substring using regex from a string. I have as a parameter a word in my function, and the goal is to extract the very next word(my definition of word) after this match. I have tried lookbehind and some other logics, but I failed to obtain the results so any help is welcome.

As example, given the first case, I have as input in my function:        `**THttpServer**`

```
23:25:04.805: INFO: THttpServer: transportTCPChanged(state: DISCONNECTED 2)
23:25:13.120: INFO: THttpServer: transportUDPOpened(state: Port 54)
```

Expected result: `transportTCPChanged` and `transportUDPOpened` for both cases.

Another case, I have as input **CurrentUserConnection**

```
23:25:16.622: INFO: CurrentUserConnection#1:RQ : subscribed(userID: 1)
23:25:16.622: INFO: CurrentUserConnection#8:RP : disconnected
```

Expected result: `subscribed, disconnected`.

Things I have tried (the lookbehind changes depending on the example) on Notepad++:

`(?<=THttpServer)(\w+)` : No matches
  `(?<=THttpServer)(.*)` : Obviously returns all the sentence, not expected match

I am bit confused, maybe it's not even possible? Or do I need some pre-processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match `:` after `THttpServer` and any non-word chars up to the word and match and *capture* it with `(\w+)`.

E.g. you may use

```
THttpServer:\W*(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lcXeRJ/1).

**Details**

- `THttpServer:` - a literal substring
- `\W*` - any 0+ non-word chars
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1 (later accessible via `m.group(1)`): 1 or more word chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JhkwZN):

```
import re
strs = ['23:25:04.805: INFO: THttpServer: transportTCPChanged(state: DISCONNECTED 2)',
        '23:25:13.120: INFO: THttpServer: transportUDPOpened(state: Port 54)']

rx = re.compile(r'THttpServer:\W*(\w+)')
for s in strs:
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m:
        print("Found '{}' in '{}'.".format(m.group(1), s))
```

Output:

```
Found 'transportTCPChanged' in '23:25:04.805: INFO: THttpServer: transportTCPChanged(state: DISCONNECTED 2)'.
Found 'transportUDPOpened' in '23:25:13.120: INFO: THttpServer: transportUDPOpened(state: Port 54)'.
```

Comment: I am trying to do so, but with Notepad++ at least it's not working. I like testing it before implementing on python, you know why?

Comment: @AlejandroA  I do not know what "not working" means. The regex I suggest works in both Python `re` and NPP Boost regex libraries equally. Hint: always test your regexps in *compatible* environments. E.g., at regex101.com, you may set the Python option and test-drive your patterns there. It [even generates the code](https://regex101.com/r/lcXeRJ/1/codegen?language=python) for you.

Comment: it worked on python as you proposed, thank you very much